# plotting point data in Mapview - non-linear scale for point symbol sizes?

Tags: r, plot, leaflet, r-mapview

Is there a way with the `mapview` library to plot the size of point symbols using a non-linear scale? For example, with geometric intervals, a custom vector of intervals, or intervals based on something like the Jenks' natural breaks method? (`mapview`'s 'setting point size 'cex' linearly': https://r-spatial.github.io/mapview/articles/articles/mapview_02-advanced.html )

My use case is plotting many points of river gage flow data, but enormously high and low values at the coast from ocean tides dominate the scale, to a point that essentially all of the non-coastal locations appear to have symbol sizes (representing river flow) that are barely discernibly different, whereas I'm hoping the user can easily visualize differences like creeks vs rivers (eg here, three groups with values in the 1000s, another in the 5000s, and another in the 9000s).

```
library(mapview)
library(sf)

lat <- seq(1, 20, 1)
lon <- lat
value_to_visualize <- c(461000, 1500, 1400, 1450, 1350, 1100, 1400, 2000, 9040, 9060, 
                    9080, 9990, 9995, 5750, 5500, 5400, 5300, 5100, 5050, -60000)

df <- data.frame(lat,lon, value_to_visualize)
df <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) 

m <- mapview(df["value_to_visualize"], 
         cex = "value_to_visualize",
         legend = TRUE,
         layer.name = "cfs")  
m
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(mapview)
library(sf)

lat <- seq(1, 20, 1)
lon <- lat
value_to_visualize <- c(461000, 1500, 1400, 1450, 1350, 1100, 1400, 2000, 9040, 9060, 
                        9080, 9990, 9995, 5750, 5500, 5400, 5300, 5100, 5050, -60000)


cluster_to_visualize <- dplyr::case_when(value_to_visualize<1000 ~ 1,
                                         value_to_visualize<5000 ~ 3,
                                         value_to_visualize<9000 ~ 5,
                                         value_to_visualize>9000 ~ 7)

df <- data.frame(lat,lon, cluster_to_visualize, value_to_visualize)
df <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) 

m <- mapview(df["value_to_visualize"], 
             cex = df$cluster_to_visualize,
             legend = TRUE,
             layer.name = "cfs")
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

[image]

Comment: thank you @M-M, though what if I'd prefer to still be able to mouse over the points to see the original (non-grouped) values?

Comment: Are you open to using `plotly`? I think you can change the `hoveinfo` in `mapview` as well but just haven't been working with it that closely. Let me give it a try in `mapview` first

Comment: thanks! I'm open to `plotly` but think I'll need it to be able to add WMS tiles like mapview and also show a good amount of metadata similar to mapview's/leaflet's popup table feature.

Comment: @doconnor see my edits. I am using `value_to_visualize` but `cex` is based on `cluster_to_visualize`.